# SQL query with one to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

Table1

```
id  name   col1   col2 col3    col4
-----------------------------------
1   test    1.1    1.2  1.3     1.4
2   test2   2.1    2.2  2.3     2.4
```

Table2

```
id  fk_table1  amt  type(fk_table3)
-----------------------------------
1     1         2     1
2     1         3     1
3     1         9     2
4     2         1     1
```

and I want to query such that I have get below result

```
id | name | total_type1_amt |total_type2_amt |  col1   col2  col3  col4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   test      5 (2+3)          9                 1.1    1.2    1.3 1.4 
2   test2     1                0                 2.1    2.2    2.3  2.4
```

Basically in result I want group by table1.id with added columns for total_typeX_amt, there will be millions of rows in table1 and table2 so basically looking for optimized way to do it.

Comment: Why do the first two rows of `table2` get their `amt` summed and the third row of `table2` will be transformed into another column? And why does the fourth row of `table2` leads to a `0` for `total_type2_amt`? Very confusing.

Comment: Very straight pivot, but what have you tried? Why don't think your current solution not optimized?

Comment: Where is table3 in all of this? You mention a FK for that table, and it appears to need that to create the different 'types'...

Comment: Search the SO for dynamic pivot, there are some nice answers here. Or maybe: aggregate in the database, and pivot in the presentation layer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.name,
       t2.total_type1_amt,
       t2.total_type2_amt
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT fk_table1,
           SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amt END) AS total_type1_amt,
           SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN amt END) AS total_type2_amt
    GROUP BY fk_table1
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.fk_table1
```

If you need this to run fast, you can try creating a view using the subquery (which I called `t2` above), with an index on the `fk_table1` column.  Assuming that `table1` also has an index on `id`, then the join should run reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% your desired result, but you could try something like

```
select fk_table1, type, sum(amt)
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_table1
group by fk_table1, type
```

which should lead to something like

```
fk_table1 | type | sum
1           1      5
1           2      9
2           1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

try dis to get total for total_type1_amt

```
 select table1.id, table2.name ,(select count(table2.amt) as total_type1_amt where table1.id = table2.fk_table1 from table.1) from table1 
    inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
    group by table.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.name,
    SUM(CASE T2.type WHEN 1 THEN T2.amt ELSE 0 END) AS total_type1_amt,
    SUM(CASE T2.type WHEN 2 THEN T2.amt ELSE 0 END) AS total_type2_amt
FROM @tbl1 T1
LEFT JOIN @tbl2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.fk_table1
GROUP BY T1.id,T1.name
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This works in the specific small case mentioned in the question, but isn't scalable. What happens when there are more than 2 TypeIDs in tbl2?

Answer (score 0):

There at least 2 ways:

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t1.name,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN amt END),0) AS total_type1_amt,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 2 THEN amt END),0) AS total_type2_amt,
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.fk_table1
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Another:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  
SELECT  t1.id,
        t1.name,
        t2.[type],
        SUM(t2.amt) as sum
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.fk_table1
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t2.[type]
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX(sum) FOR type IN ([1],[2])
) as pvt
```

Comment: so with 1st approach i had to do group by all the coloums of t1 which i wanted to select, in my case there are around 10 such coloums so does this means i need to add more coloums to group by?

Comment: 10 types you mean? Or columns like `id`, `name` etc? If you have many `types` - use dynamic SQL, if you got more columns to GROUP BY - just mentioned them twice - in SELECT and GROUP BY parts.

Comment: i modified my question,added more coloums to table1 , so in that case i need to add that many group by right?

Comment: Yes, I add this in the first part of my answer

Comment: if i add in group by then i guess query will become slow

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  fk_table1, SUM([1]) total_type1_amt, COALESCE(SUM([2]), 0) total_type2_amt
FROM #table1 PIVOT (MAX(amt) FOR type IN ([1], [2])) p
GROUP BY fk_table1)
SELECT
  t.id, t.name, c.total_type1_amt, c.total_type2_amt
FROM #table1 t
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON t.id = c.fk_table1
```